# Сложный поиск совпадающих значений по нескольким критериям в нескольких DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, обработка-данных

Есть два DF.

Первый:

```
FIRM    TT  YEAR    x1  x2  x3
A   0   2010    6   3   5
A   0   2011    4   2   9
A   0   2012    1   5   5
A   1   2010    4   9   7
B   0   2010    3   10  1
B   0   2011    5   10  8
B   1   2010    9   3   3
B   1   2011    1   1   1
B   1   2012    4   1   9
C   0   2010    5   5   9
C   0   2011    1   8   2
```

и второй:

```
FIRM    TT  YEAR    X4
A   0   2008    5
A   0   2009    6
A   0   2010    3
A   0   2011    2
A   0   2012    5
A   0   2013    9
B   0   2010    10
B   1   2009    10
B   1   2010    3
B   1   2011    1
B   1   2012    1
C   0   2010    5
C   1   2011    8
```

У обоих DF совпадают три колонки : `FIRM, TT, YEAR`.

В чем состоит задача: необходимо взять каждую строку из первого DF и найти ей соответствие по этим трем совпадающим столбцам во втором DF и на выходе вывести уже новый DF, где добавится `x4`. Если совпадений нет, то эта строка просто напросто не выводится в новом DF.

На выходе должно получиться нечто такое:

```
FIRM    TT  YEAR    x1  x2  x3  x4
A   0   2010    6   3   5   3
A   0   2011    4   2   9   2
A   0   2012    1   5   5   5
B   0   2010    3   10  1   10
B   1   2010    9   3   3   3
B   1   2011    1   1   1   1
B   1   2012    4   1   9   1
C   0   2010    5   5   9   5
```

Answer (score 1):

по умолчанию метод [d1.merge(d2)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) объединяет фреймы по всем столбцам с совпадающими именами:

```
In [114]: res = d1.merge(d2)

In [115]: res
Out[115]:
  FIRM  TT  YEAR  x1  x2  x3  X4
0    A   0  2010   6   3   5   3
1    A   0  2011   4   2   9   2
2    A   0  2012   1   5   5   5
3    B   0  2010   3  10   1  10
4    B   1  2010   9   3   3   3
5    B   1  2011   1   1   1   1
6    B   1  2012   4   1   9   1
7    C   0  2010   5   5   9   5
```